# JSON coming from server with quotes and regular expression

Tags: javascript, python, json, post

I'm analysing the way a server of a search page works (by inspecting element) and I could conclude that the request is sent with a POST with JSON as parameters.
Then I simulated the same POST (with the same parameters) using Insomnia. It was successful, but the response JSON came as string and inside the JSON, variables that uses quotes now uses \" instead.

An example of the JSON response:

```
"{\"AudienceRefiner\":{\"ItemCount\":0}}"
```

How can I read this on Python?

Comment: How you are you going to put double quotes (`"`) inside a string that has double quotes as delimiters: **you must escape the inner double quotes using `\\`**.

Comment: looks like some object has been double JSONified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just an escape character, Consider using the ast library in order to parse it into an object.

> literal_eval:
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
> string containing a Python literal or container display.

```
import ast
st = "{\"AudienceRefiner\":{\"ItemCount\":0}}"

obj = ast.literal_eval(st)
print (obj)
>>> {'AudienceRefiner': {'ItemCount': 0}}
```

For more information about it, read [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know the name of this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got `"{\"AudienceRefiner\":{\"ItemCount\":0}}"` I guess that its not is python but webbrowser. Anyhow just use json if the json is in a string object

```
import json
di = json.loads("{\"AudienceRefiner\":{\"ItemCount\":0}}")
```

Comment: I used Insomnia for the request, not Python. I thought it wasn't readable for Python, but now it's clear. Thanks.